# Delete github respository via API

Tags: github

I want to delete a list of repositories using the github API. But I get the response:

> {   "message": "Bad credentials",   "documentation_url":
>   "https://developer.github.com/v3" }

#### Steps to reproduce

First I created a personal access token here: https://github.com/settings/tokens

I made sure it had the scope `delete_repo`

[image]

Then, create a variable for my token
`export GITHUB_TOKEN=asasfsafaffafsafafsfs`

Finally run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

repos=(
    "my_username/test-1"
)

for i in "${repos[@]}"
do
   :
   curl -XDELETE -H 'Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN' "https://api.github.com/repos/$i ";
done
```

Changing the header to `'Authorization: $GITHUB_TOKEN'` gives

> {   "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",
>   "documentation_url":
>   "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository" }

Searching the error and reading the provided link does not help me. How can I not have admin rights to my own repository (it's not in an org)? I have also tried checking *everything* in the personal access token generation page without effect.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command (plugging in user, token, and repo)

```
curl -u $user:$token -XDELETE "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo"
```

Answer (score 2):

You must generate a token which includes the delete_repo scope through this page: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new