# "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository." for personal token in standard github account

Tags: rest, postman, token, github-api-v3

I am using Github API with the personal access token, from a standard GitHub account.

although the token has the permission to delete the repo.

I am still getting :

'''
{

```
"message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",

"documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository"
```

}
'''

My question is similar to this [Delete github respository via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353365/delete-github-respository-via-api/63041591#63041591), but it doesn't have any answer.